BitBucket PAT token creation automatization
We have multiple Bitbucket repos and HTTP tokens per repo/project. Our security team mandates to set the expiration to 90 days.
Is there a way to programmatically refresh these tokens via API calls?
Can I use an already existing HTTP token to create a new one?
I've tried going through BitBucket docs but they haven't really been helpful.

are you using Server or Cloud?
